# More effective way to remove first and last object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I currently have the following code below.  This works fine, but I think there is a more efficient way to do "shift" and "pop" without doing them one after the other.  Still understanding how it all works, so any tips/tricks/recommandations would be appreciated

I am looping through each list item, getting the value and then adding it to the array.  Once I have them, as seen below I remove the first and last values as the waypts are only meant to be the spots between the first and last (if any are available)

```
var waypts = [];
var inputArray = $('#enter-destinations li').each(function () {
    var thisAddress = $(this).find('input').val();
    waypts.push({ location : thisAddress, stopover: true });
});

waypts.shift(); //remove first
waypts.pop(); //remove last
console.log(waypts); //show values that were between first and last
```

Comment: that's actually a good way of doing it, otherwise you'll need to create a new array using `waypts.slice(1,-1)`

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but maybe you should ask that on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GuiImamura no being rude at all, I was totally ignorant to that being available

Comment: @RichardHamilton: no, slice cannot combine shift+pop because slice immutably yields a new array while shift/pop mutate the source array.

Comment: I believe the best way is to avoid adding them in the first place, skip the first and last iteration of the `.each()`, see my answer below.

Comment: @dandavis i kept it as is, I greatlly appreciate everyones feed back and examples I was able to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `pop` and `shift` are faster then `slice` as you can see in this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/popshiftvsslice).

`slice` creates a new array while `pop` and `shift` manipulate the current array.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array#slice`.

```
waypts = waypts.slice(1, waypts.length - 1)
```

Comment: `slice(1,-1)` is faster than length-1, but it still breaks the array ref.

Comment: not really, because this method is immutable, I am passing the value of the function to the original variable

Comment: well, it does work but you're not passing back to the org variable, you're re-assigning to the same variable name. any aliases of array would not be edited, even by re-assigning.

Answer (score 2):

Just skip the first and last elements when looping through the array:

```
var waypts = [];
var inputArray = $('#enter-destinations li')

if(inputArary.length > 2) {
  for(var i = 1; i < inputArray.length - 1; i += 1) {
    var thisAddress = $(inputArray[i]).find('input').val();
    waypts.push({
      location: thisAddress,
      stopover: true
    });
  }
}

console.log(waypts); //show values that were between first and last
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the index directly in the jQuery `.each()` loop to avoid adding them in the first place. You also avoid 2x `.find()` and 2x `.push`.

```js
var waypts = [];
var elem = $('#enter-destinations li');
var total = (elem.length-1); // get last index
var inputArray = elem.each(function (index) { // index tells you what iteration you are at
    if(index != total && index != 0){
        var thisAddress = $(this).find('input').val();
        waypts.push({ location : thisAddress, stopover: true });
    }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(waypts)); //show values that were between first and last
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="enter-destinations">
<li><input type="text" value="waypoint 1" /></li>
<li><input type="text" value="waypoint 2" /></li>
<li><input type="text" value="waypoint 3" /></li>
<li><input type="text" value="waypoint 4" /></li>
</ul>
```